# Formatting the string result of text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio, superagent

Good day, do anyone know how to format or add some extra string (*like a comma*),to the results given by **text()**? I am using it in web scraping.

Here's the snippet of the scraper:

```
var makeupCatBrand = $('span.caption').children('h6').text().trim()
```

Here's the result when I use `console.log(makeupCatBrand)`:

> Jeffree StarCharlotte TilburyRCMA MakeupNatasha DenonaAnna SuiJeffree StarSugarpillAnna SuiArmour BeautyOCCSugarpillCover FXIT Cosmetics rms beautyMake-Up AtelierCover FXCover FXIT Cosmetics beautyblenderBY TERRYKevyn AucoinbeautyblenderIT Cosmetics Charlotte TilburyBY TERRYCover FXViseartCover FXWayne GossRCMA MakeupAnna SuiAnna SuiCover FXOCCAnna SuiCharlotte Tilbury

I tried pushing it to an array, but all of that shows only as one index in the array.

I would like to add at least a comma per brand (*Jeffree Star, Charlotte Tilbury, etc*) so that i can easily split it before pushing to an array. Any answer or idea is greatly appreciated

Oh, they all have the same class, no ID, that's why it will be quite hard if I were to scrape them one by one

Here's the html code of two of the brand (*all of them had the same format, so I only include one, the only change if a product with that brand had two or more available shades*):

```
<li class="shop_t_browse">
    <a class="tile" href="/p/jeffree-star-velour-liquid-lipstick" >
        <span class="img txt_c">
            <img class="inlineblock"     src="//dy6g3i6a1660s.cloudfront.net/eNiRpXtM7WlLKE7qyhAw4AR-BH4/320_p-cd/jeffree-star-velour-liquid-lipstick.jpg" alt="Jeffree Star Velour Liquid Lipstick" />
        </span>
        <span class="caption">

            <h6>Jeffree Star</h6>
            <h5>Velour Liquid Lipstick</h5>
            <p><strong>$18 USD</strong></p>
            <small class="shop_msg_color">
                24 shades available
            </small>
            <small class="rating_reviews txt_pale hidden_mobile">
                <div class="ratingInfo">
                    <span class="rating_image_small" style="background-position: 0 -250.0000000000px;"></span>
                    <span class="txt_pale glyph_stat"> / 674</span>
                </div>
            </small>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Add the HTML code that contains that information.

Comment: what does `$('span.caption').children('h6')` return?

Comment: @JoeHanink It's quite long in the console log, I'll edit my post to show some html code of the brands

Comment: it's strange, you start with an array (selector to h6) and then you want to join them with commas so that you can split them on the comma back into an array...

Comment: @JoeHanink I thought that it's only strings being concatenated to each other. I thought of pushing it to an array as the code scrape through the h6's, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of what I see you can, since you seem to have multiple children, go through each of them separately.

So this is how it could work.

```
var makeupCatBrand;
$('span.caption').children('h6').each(function(){
    makeupCatBrand += $(this).text().trim();
    makeupCatBrand += ", ";
})
```

Comment: This helped, but there's a undefined word in the first brand (_undefinedJeffree Star_), any idea?

Comment: Share the html with the undefined I'll give a look at work :)

Comment: The html of one of the brand is in the question, all of the other brand has the same html code so I didn't bother to copy all of them. I get that problem after I console.log makeupCatBrand. Anyway, @Christian Hedemann's answer produced the same result, but without the undefined word, but I still want to know what caused that prob for reference

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `replace()` method to replace the white space with coma or coma and white space like such:

```
makeupCatBrand.replace(" ", ",");
```

or

```
makeupCatBrand.replace(" ", ", ");
```

first argument is the part of string you want replaced, and the second argument the string you want it replaced with.

you can also use `split()` method to get an array of strings like such:

```
var strArray = makeupCatBrand.split(" ");
```

You can split the string as is so you can add a coma and whit space if you want to keep it in the end result.

Comment: Tnx for answering :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var children = $('span.caption').children('h6');

var resultsArray = [];
for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
  resultsArray[i] = children[i].textContent;
}

console.log(resultsArray);
```

working code - http://jsbin.com/hozasahota/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: where, in the jsbin?

Comment: I tried it in my codes, but it returned a number of undefined the same as the length

Answer (score 0):

One line, seperating with ',':

```
var makeupCatBrand = $('span.caption').children('h6').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).get().join(',');
```

...as it is  the ',' can be omitted as it is default. I placed it in the code to show that the seperator can be customized.

Comment: This helped too, slightly better than my accepted answer, tnx!

Answer (score -1):

```javascript
var arr = [];
$('span.caption').children('h6').each(function()
{
    arr.push($(this).text().trim());
});
console.log(arr.join(","));
```